# How to fetch the text from the textbox and save it into Xml using Linq

Tags: xml, linq

I have made three text box and want to fetch and write the data in the XML file in C# using Linq.How can i do this.This is my XML Structure

```
<Complains>
<Complain>
<ComplaintID/>
<Comments/>
<Date_Of_resolved/>
<Resolved_by>12-09-1992</Resolved_by>
</Complain>
</Complains>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "using LINQ" do you mean "using LINQ to XML"? (I can't see any need for queries here.) How far have you got so far? At the moment this looks like a "gimmetehcodez" question with no research effort.

Comment: @zombie, Where to record the information from the TextBox? In ComplaintID, Comments, Date_Of_resolved and Resolved_by to keep constant 12-09-1992?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't answer my clarifying question, i will answer as i understand:

If you want a create new .xml:

```
    int id = 0;
    string b = "B";
    string c = "C";

    var xd = new XDocument(
                new XElement("Complains",
                  new XElement("Complain",
                      new XElement("ComplaintID", id),
                      new XElement("Comments", b),
                      new XElement("Date_Of_resolved", c),
                      new XElement("Resolved_by", "12-09-1992")
                      )));

    xd.Save("s1.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(xd);
```

Print:

```
<Complains>
  <Complain>
    <ComplaintID>0</ComplaintID>
    <Comments>B</Comments>
    <Date_Of_resolved>C</Date_Of_resolved>
    <Resolved_by>12-09-1992</Resolved_by>
  </Complain>
</Complains>
```

Change id,b,c on text from textboxes

If you want to write to an existing file. Then use the Add method:    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.add(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    var xd = XDocument.Load("s1.xml");
    int id = 1;
    string b = "D";
    string c = "F";
    xd.Root.Add(new XElement("Complain",
                      new XElement("ComplaintID", id),
                      new XElement("Comments", b),
                      new XElement("Date_Of_resolved", c),
                      new XElement("Resolved_by", "12-09-1992")
                      ));
    Console.WriteLine(xd);
    xd.Save("s1.xml");
```

Print:

```
<Complains>
  <Complain>
    <ComplaintID>0</ComplaintID>
    <Comments>B</Comments>
    <Date_Of_resolved>C</Date_Of_resolved>
    <Resolved_by>12-09-1992</Resolved_by>
  </Complain>
  <Complain>
    <ComplaintID>1</ComplaintID>
    <Comments>D</Comments>
    <Date_Of_resolved>F</Date_Of_resolved>
    <Resolved_by>12-09-1992</Resolved_by>
  </Complain>
</Complains>
```

Sorry for my English. I hope my answer was useful to you.